Understanding the `model.fit` function in keras and imbalanced datasets
As an exercise, I'm trying to translate a model written in Keras (https://github.com/CVxTz/ECG_Heartbeat_Classification/blob/master/code/baseline_mitbih.py) into Pytorch code. I realize in Keras much of the training part is abstracted into the function model.fit() function, while in Pytorch one has to be explicit. The dataset that is used to train the aforementioned model can be found on kaggle (/kaggle/input/heartbeat/mitbih_test.csv).By the looks of it the data is imbalanced towards one of the five classes.
Converting the model to Pytorch is rather simple, but writing a good training routine has proved to be challenging. A standard method to circumvent dataset imbalance is using weighted cross entropy loss. I computed the class_weights using sklearn's compute_class_weight_function which was then fed to the CrossEntropyLoss function. However, with this approach the loss doesn't go down as one would expect. My code for the training routine is given below:
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nclass):
        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.conv6 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        
        self.conv7 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.conv8 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dtype=float)
        self.global_max_pool = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 64, dtype=float)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64, dtype=float)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, nclass, dtype=float)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv6(x))
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.dropout3(x)
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv7(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv8(x))
        
        x = self.global_max_pool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)  # Flatten the output for fully connected layers
        x = self.dropout4(x)
        
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        
        return torch.softmax(x, dim=1)

# Hyperparameters
input_dim = 187  # Original time series length
num_classes = 5  # Number of output classes

# Instantiate the model
model = Model(num_classes)
# print(model)
model.to(device)
# Define loss function and optimizer
class_weights=class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',classes=np.unique(Y),y=Y.numpy())
class_weights=torch.tensor(class_weights,dtype=torch.float64).to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train the model
n_epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    model.train()
    last_loss = 0
    running_loss = 0
    
    for i, (X_batch, Y_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        X_batch = X_batch.to(device)
        Y_batch = Y_batch.to(device)
        output = model(X_batch)
        loss = criterion(output, Y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
     
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 200 == 199:
            last_loss = running_loss / 200 # loss per batch
            print('  batch {} loss: {}'.format(i + 1, last_loss))
            running_loss = 0.


On the Keras side, simply calling
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)

does the trick, where X and Y are the training data and targets respectively. There is no additional input provided about the distribution of the data. How does model.fit() differ from my training code? Does it do something different when it comes to sampling from the dataset?
Note that the Keras implementation does not require using class_weights. On the other hand, the Pytorch implementation does not work either with or without class_weights.

do something special such as? its unclear what "special" you are expecting.

I mean to ask how the model.fit() function in Keras is different from the training routine that I wrote down. Is there something that Keras does to preprocess the data maybe?

No, the data is not preprocessed in fit, that would have to be done externally.

Ah, so that would mean that my PyTorch implementation is incorrect then? Because no matter what I do I can't get the loss to go down in value while I'm training. I added my entire PyTorch implementation. I really can't see where I might be going wrong.

The keras version does not have anything about class weights, but no idea if this is the problem or not.

Keras fit accepts class weights as an argument if provided by the user, but does not apply them automatically

The linked code is not using that functionality, that is what I am saying.

@Dr.Snoopy Perhaps I need to further clarify that the pytorch implementation does not work either with or without class weights, while the Keras implementation seems to work perfectly well without class weights. My initial suspicion was that the pytorch implementation was failing because of the imbalanced dataset - a closer examination revealed that the model was getting biased towards the majority class. Even though initializing class_weights helped with the former, it did not improve learning (the loss doesnt go down with subsequent iterations).

The current discussion points to something being wrong with my Pytorch implementation. Still unsure where.
